# What is this tiny thing on the branch

Tags: botany, species-identification, entomology

I noticed a tiny spot with weird shape on the shoot of a plant (Variegata), and there are many others on other branches. I wonder what is it, this is a cropped picture of it, Thank you!
 [image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a female of yet another [scale insect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect) (Coccoidea). We have discussed one [recently](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38874/what-are-these-white-spots-on-a-dracena/38900#38900).

I guess we can identify this one rather precisely as [*Ceroplastes sinensis*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ceroplastes+sinensis&tbm=isch) or its close relative. Species of this group are of [South American origin](http://169.237.77.3/gullanandcranstonlab/Gullanpdfs/Csorigin.pdf), but *Ceroplastes sinensis* has today an extremely broad distribution. So, if you found this plant (*"Variegata"* is a specific epithet, by the way: it would be of some help if you provided the generic name as well) in Europe or Asia it's likely *sinensis* itself.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, Very instructive,  I am not a botanist, I don't know the naming techniques, I just searched by leaf colors and I found Variegata as the closest plant, I think it's a Ficus benjamina 'Variegata'